# Fourier series of $\sqrt{1 - k^2 \sin^2{t}}$

Tags: fourier-series, elliptic-integrals

I'm struggling with a Fourier series. I need to find the Fourier series of the following function.

> That's the function under study:
>   $f(t)=\left[\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2t}\,\right]$.
>
> The function is even and $\pi$-periodic.
>
> The Fourier series should be in this form:
>   $f(t)=\frac{a_0}2+\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty a_n\cos[2nt]$.
>
> In $t\to0$, the Taylor series is:
>    $$f(t)=\left[\frac{2E[k^2]}\pi+\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac1{2^{2i-1}}\pmatrix{1/2\\
>  i}(k)^{2i}\sum_{j=0}^{i-1}(-1)^j\pmatrix{2i\\j}\cos(2(i-j)t)
> \right].$$

It's pretty close to the final Fourier serie but I cannot find the coefficient $a_n$ by identification.
Can someone give a help on this?
PS: $k\ll 1$ is real and $E(k^2)$ is the complete elliptic integral of the second kind.

Comment: TeXForm everything and put dollar signs around them.

Comment: Do you want to find Fourier series or Fourier transform?

Comment: Thanks Menni, I want the Fourier series and especially the cosine coefficient. I correct the problem statement to avoid misunderstanding.

Comment: Thanks Mehnni. Sorry for the typo in your name.

Comment: If I start directly from the integral of the cosine coefficient, it comes that $a_n$ should be a some of complete elliptic integral of 1st kind  $K(k^2)$ and 2nd kind $E(k^2)$ as it can be guessed from several integration by parts: $\frac{2 \int_0^{\pi } \sqrt{1-k^2 \sin ^2(t)} \cos (2 n t) \, dt}{\pi }$=$\int_0^{\pi }-\frac{2 k^2 \sin (2 \text{nt}) \sin (x) \cos (x)}{\pi  \sqrt{1-k^2 \sin ^2(x)}}$
I don't know really well the properties of the elliptic Integrals. Does someone have an idea?

Comment: If I didn't make any mistake, we have

$$\begin{align}
&\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2t}\cos(2nt)dt\\
= & \frac{1 + \sqrt{1-k^2}}{2} \frac{(-\frac12)_n(-\lambda^2)^n}{n!} 
{}_2F_1\left(-\frac12, n-\frac12; n+1; \lambda^4\right)
\end{align}$$
where 
$\displaystyle\;\lambda = \frac{k}{1 + \sqrt{1-k^2}},\;$
$(\gamma)_n = \gamma(\gamma+1)\cdots(\gamma+n-1)$ is the rising
[Pochhammer symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pochhammer_symbol)
and ${}_2F_1$ is the [hypergeometric function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function).

Comment: It seems for each $n$, the expression on RHS can be rewritten as linear combination of [complete elliptic integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral) $K(k)$ and $E(k)$
but I haven't figure out the correct coefficients.

Comment: @achillehui: One thought from prior experience is to find the ODE satisfied by that hypergeometric function, show that both kinds of elliptic integrals show up as solutions, and then use boundary conditions to fix the coefficients in that basis.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an approach. We expand the function $f(x)$ using its Taylor series as

> $$ f(x)= \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}{ -\frac{1}{2} \choose m }(-1)^m k^{2m}\sin^{2m}(t) . $$

We need to find $a_n$ which are given by

> $$ a_n=\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x)\cos(nx)dx =\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}{ -\frac{1}{2} \choose m }(-1)^m k^{2m}\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \sin^{2m}(t)\cos(nx)dx . $$

Now your job to evaluate the last integral and try to finish the problem.