# Closed-form of sums from Fourier series of $\sqrt{1-k^2 \sin^2 x}$

Tags: fourier-analysis, special-functions, closed-form, elliptic-integrals

Consider the even $\pi$-periodic function $f(x,k)=\sqrt{1-k^2 \sin^2 x}$ with Fourier cosine series $$f(x,k)=\frac{1}{2}a_0+\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \cos2nx,\quad a_n=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi} \sqrt{1-k^2 \sin^2 x}\cos 2nx \,dx.$$ This was considered in this earlier [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/930003/137524), and in comments an observation was made: The Fourier coefficients all appear to be of the form $a_n= A_n(k) K(k)+B_n(k) E(k)$ where $K,E$ are the complete elliptic integrals of the first and second kind and $A_n(k),B_n(k)$ are rational functions of $k$.

This is made plausible by the fact that $f(x,k)$ is the first $x$-derivative of the *incomplete* elliptic integral of the second kind $E(x,k)=\int_0^x f(x',k)\,dx'$. Moreover, this conjecture for $a_k$ can be confirmed by examining the Fourier series of $E(x,k)$; this appears in a 2010 paper by D. Cvijovic, with full text available on [ResearchGate](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/233461553_The_Fourier_series_expansions_of_the_Legendre_incomplete_elliptic_integrals_of_the_first_and_second_kind).

Something we may conclude from this observation is that, since the Fourier coefficients are linear combinations of complete elliptic integrals, $f(x,k)$ itself must be of the form $A(x,k)K(k)+B(x,k)E(k)$ where $A(x,k), B(x,k)$ are even $\pi$-periodic functions whose Fourier coefficients are rational functions of $k$. Such a Fourier expansion of does appear in the paper noted above, but the functions themselves are not found in closed-form. Hence my question:

> > Can $A(x,k)$, $B(x,k)$ be obtained in closed-form in terms of known special functions?

Comment: Either you or me missed something: Your $a_n=\frac{2}{\pi}E(k)\;$ do not depend on $n\;$ and therefore you would have
$$f(x,k)=\frac{2}{\pi}E(k)\Big(\frac{1}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \cos2nx\Big),$$
but the sum is not convergent.

Comment: @gammatester: silly mistake on my part. There should be a factor of $\cos(2nx)$ in the integrand (as appropriate for Fourier coefficients). I've fixed it now.

Comment: Integration by parts and elementary trigonometric identities give that we can find explicit forms of $A(x,k)$ and $B(x,k)$ iff we can solve a second-order recurrence.

Answer (score 2):

We have:
$$ \frac{\pi}{2}\,a_n=\int_{0}^{\pi}\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2\theta}\cos(2n\theta)\,d\theta =\frac{k^2}{4n}\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\sin(2\theta)\sin(2n\theta)}{\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2\theta}}\,d\theta.\tag{1}$$
If we set:
$$ b_m = \int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\cos(2m\theta)}{\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2\theta}}\,d\theta,\qquad c_m = \int_{0}^{\pi}\cos(2m\theta)\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2\theta}\,d\theta $$
we have:
$$ b_m = \int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\cos(2\theta)\cos((2m-2)\theta)}{\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2\theta}}\,d\theta-\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\sin(2\theta)\sin((2m-2)\theta)}{\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2\theta}}\,d\theta$$
and expressing $\cos(2\theta)$ as $1-2\sin^2\theta$ we get:

$$ b_m = \frac{2}{k^2}\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{(k^2/2-k^2\sin^2\theta)\cos((2m-2)\theta)}{\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2\theta}}\,d\theta-\frac{4(m-1)}{k^2}c_{m-1}$$
so:
$$ b_m = \frac{2}{k^2} c_{m-1} + \frac{k^2-2}{k^2}b_{m-1}-\frac{4m-4}{k^2}c_{m-1} = \frac{k^2-2}{k^2}b_{m-1}-\frac{4m-2}{k^2}c_{m-1}. $$

Moreover, integration by parts gives:
$$ c_m = \frac{k^2}{8m}\left(b_{m+1}-b_{m-1}\right), \tag{2}$$
hence:
$$ b_m = \frac{k^2-2}{k^2}b_{m-1}-\frac{2m-1}{4m-4}(b_m-b_{m-2}), $$
$$ \frac{6m-5}{4m-4} b_m = \frac{k^2-2}{k^2}b_{m-1}+\frac{2m-1}{4m-4}b_{m-2}, $$
or:

> $$ b_m = \frac{4m-4}{6m-5}\cdot\frac{k^2-2}{k^2}b_{m-1}+\frac{2m-1}{6m-5}b_{m-2}.\tag{3} $$

Since $b_0 = 2 K(k) $ and $c_0 = 2 E(k)$ we have
$$ b_1 = \frac{1}{k^2}\left((2k^2-4)K(k)+4E(k)\right).$$
In order to have explicit forms for $A(\theta,k)$ and $B(\theta,k)$, it is sufficient to find a closed-form expression for the recursion given by $(3)$, since, by $(1)$ and $(2)$:
$$\frac{\pi}{2}a_n = c_n = \frac{k^2}{8n}\left(b_{m+1}-b_{m-1}\right).$$

By setting: 
$$ B(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0} b_n x^n $$
recursion $(2)$ can be converted into a first-order ODE for $B(x)$, giving that $B(x)$ behaves like the reciprocal of the square root of a cubic polynomial, and the radius of convergence of $B(x)$ is $\geq 2.485$. $A(\theta,k)$ and $B(\theta,k)$ can be recovered from $\Re\left(B(e^{2i\theta})\right)$.

Comment: I like this answer quite a bit. A few questions: 1) The connection between the $a_m$ coefficients and the $b_m,c_m$ coefficients isn't stated explicitly. 2) Can your final paragraph---i.e. the solution of the recursion as an ODE---be stated explicitly? The sketch makes sense, but details would be nice... 3) I think there's some inconsistency between $\theta$ and $x$ between/within this answer and my OP.

Comment: @Semiclassical: I'll fix my answer soon, just have a little patience since I've got to travel a bit now :)

Comment: I was going back through my questions, and noticed that this one never got updated. Could I bother you to follow through on expanding this?