# Square root of a Fourier series

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

This problem came to mind in conjunction with two earlier ones [[1]](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1061251/137524) [[2]](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/930003/137524.).

> > Let $f(x)$ be positive square-integrable function on $[0,2\pi]$ with Fourier series $\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} c_k e^{i k x}$. Then the principal square root $\sqrt{f(x)}$ is well-defined on $[0,2\pi]$. How do the Fourier coefficients of $\sqrt{f(x)}$ on this interval depend on $c_k$?

Comment: After experimenting a bit, I don't see an obvious relationship. What kind of relationship are you hoping for?

Comment: @CameronWilliams: honestly, I'm not sure what to hope for; this is essentially a vast generalization of the two linked questions, neither of which have answers which satisfy me. So if a nice answer were to somehow exist for this question, it would presumably clarify those two as well.

Comment: If $\sqrt{f}=\sum_{k}s_{k}e^{ikx}$, then you can multiply the series by itself and gather like terms to get $f=\sum_{k}\left[\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}s_{k-n}s_{n}\right]e^{ikx}$. There's not much you can say after that.

Comment: The relation $f(x)=\sqrt{f(x)}\sqrt{f(x)}$ yields (for example by "multiplying out") to $c_k = (d \ast d)_k = \sum_\ell d_{k-\ell} d_\ell$, where $d=(d_k)_k$ are the Fourier coefficients of $\sqrt{f}$. But this is a very implicit relation which will probably not help you much.

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in the comments, there is no formula giving the Fourier coefficients of $\sqrt f$ in terms of the coefficients of $f$. Let $f(x)=1+t\,\cos x$ for $|t|\le1$. It is clear that $f(x)\ge0$ if $x\in[-\pi,\pi]$. For simplicity I will consider real instead of Fourier coefficients. Since $f$ is even, all sine Fourier coefficients vanish. The Fourier series of $f$ has only two coefficients different from cero, but
$$
\int_{-\pi}^\pi \sqrt{f(x)}\,\cos(n\,x)\,dx=2 \pi  \sqrt{1-t} \,
   _3\tilde{F}_2\left(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},1;1-n,n+1;\frac{2 t}{t-1}\right).
$$ 
Computation done in Mathematica.